# Position Absolute issues

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack two divs on top of each other (meaning they overlap) b/c the div below has an image (Yelp logo) that is an awkward size. I used "position: absolute" - but instead of those divs resting on top of each other, the divs to the right collapse into them (and the divs I'm trying to collapse don't).

How do I fix this? Or does it make more sense to just give the div containing the Yelp logo a negative margin?

For clarification, here's the site: www.valleylawyermarketing.com

And this is what it should look like: But with the Yelp breaking into the div above.

[image]

```
<div class="testimonial logos cycle-slide cycle-slide-active" style="z-index: 99; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; display: block; opacity: 1;">
<div class="box">
<div class="yelp">
<p>More reviews:</p>
<div class="images2">
<img class="" src="http://mrodriguez.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/roots-master/assets/img/yelp.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="also-part">
<p>We're also part of:</p>
<div class="images">
<img class="" src="http://mrodriguez.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/google-partner.png">
<img class="" src="http://mrodriguez.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/yext-partner.png">
<img class="" src="http://mrodriguez.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bbb-logo.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>

.logos .box {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
.logos .yelp {
    position: absolute;
}
.logos .images2 {
    position: absolute;
}
.logos .also-part {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
.logos .images {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `<div>` elements are block-level and will position themselves one above the other without any CSS.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I know that. But how can I get them to stack on top of each other (sharing the same area) - vs being on top of one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want all of the logos to be on one line, next to each other horizontally and have the Yelp logo be aligned slightly higher to compensate for the tallness of the logo. I'd recommend losing the absolute positioning and instead use a negative margin on the image to pull it up slightly.

```
.logos .box {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
.logos .also-part {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
.logos img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.logos .yelp img {
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/2nkjxahc/2/

Answer (score 0):

like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5dbjuLof/

Just remove the float and every position absolute and they will stack

```
.logos .also-part {
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
}
.logos .images {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have two divs on top of each other (with the div below going into the div above). Those two divs use 30% of the width. To the right of that, the top divs and images below use 70%. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you create a quick mockup of what you're trying to accomplish please?

Comment: Hi. I did. I edited my original post. Sorry for not being clear. Really hard to explain via words.

Comment: Hi. B/c of the odd shape of the Yelp logo, I want the div containing the YELP logo to overlap with the div above it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I just did a negative margin. That seems like the easiest way to go.

Thanks again.